# PartialView - How to pass a single object when View receives an IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal, partial-views

I have a Model (Machines) with it's Controller. The Controller which, in the  Index action 'IActionResult', collects a list of Machines and send it to the Index view.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
    ViewData["NameSortParm"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "nombre_desc" : "";
    ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
    ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

    var maquinas = from s in _context.Machines
                   select s;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        maquinas = maquinas.Where(s => s.MchName.Contains(searchString));
    }
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "nombre_desc":
            maquinas = maquinas.OrderByDescending(s => s.MchName);
            break;
        case "Date":
            maquinas = maquinas.OrderBy(s => s.FechaCompra);
            break;
        case "date_desc":
            maquinas = maquinas.OrderByDescending(s => s.FechaCompra);
            break;
        default:
            maquinas = maquinas.OrderBy(s => s.MchName);
            break;
    }
    return View(await _context.Machines.Include(t => t.MachineTypes).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
}
```

In the Index, I present this list on a table:

```
@model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Machine>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            Search by name: <input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["currentFilter"]" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            <a asp-action="Index">Volver a lista completa</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
                <th>
                    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["NameSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MchName)</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MachineTypes.TypeDescription)
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["DateSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FechaCompra)</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CostoMaq)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PUnit)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FechaPUnit)
                </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MchName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MachineTypes.TypeDescription)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaCompra)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CostoMaq)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PUnit)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaPUnit)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see I have a asp-action called "Create" which opens the Create view where the user can register a new machine.

Here is the code from the Machine Controller for the Create():
**Note: Create is a View, not a PartialView yet**

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    PopulateMachineTypeDropDownList();
    PopulateMachineTypeDropDownListSupplier();
    PopulateMachineTypeDropDownListStore();

    return View();
}
```

**Objective:**

Call the Create form as a modal from inside the Index.cshtml (as a partial view?)

For this, I edited the Index.cshtml and converted this:

```
<a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
```

Into this:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="CreateModal">Create New</a>
```

Also, I inserted the modal code at the end of the table listing the machines we have in stock and tried to invoke the Create view as a Partial View. (which failed, of course). Modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="CreateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.RenderPartial("Create", Model)
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I believe this fails for many reasons, using a RenderPartial on something not defined as a partialview is one and I hope is the main reason.

**Question:**

What steps should I follow to convert the Create view into a partialview inside the Index.cshtml and present it as a modal form?

By the way, this is the code for the Create view at the moment:

```
@model Application.Models.Machine

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<form asp-action="Create">

        <h4>Machine</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TypeID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="TypeID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TypeID">
                    <option value="">-- Seleccione Tipo --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="TypeID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="SupplierID" class="col-md-2 control-label">    </label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="SupplierID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.SupplierID">
                    <option value="">-- Seleccione Proveedor --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="SupplierID" class="text-danger">    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="StoreID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="StoreID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StoreID">
                    <option value="">-- Seleccione Tienda --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="StoreID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="MchName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="MchName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MchName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FechaCompra" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="FechaCompra" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FechaCompra" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CostoMaq" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="CostoMaq" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CostoMaq" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="PUnit" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="PUnit" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PUnit" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FechaPUnit" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="FechaPUnit" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FechaPUnit" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its my old code I think it will help you. Its not same as yours but you will get
 Partial View:

```
@model App.Domain.PostOffice
        <div class="modal fade" id="Addmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Post Office</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body form-horizontal ">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row" id="rptshow">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="card-box table-responsive">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
                                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PoId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PoId, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", disabled = "disabled" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", required = "required" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", required = "required", })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PostCode, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PostCode, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", required = "required", data_parsley_minlength = "4", type = "number", palceholder = "" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Hpo, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Hpo, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", required = "required", data_parsley_Maxlength = "2", data_parsley_minlength = "2", type = "number", palceholder = "" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Gpo, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Gpo, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", required = "required", data_parsley_Maxlength = "2", data_parsley_minlength = "2", type = "number", palceholder = "" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" id="add">Save changes</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

@model App.Domain.PostOffice

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Addmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Post Office</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body form-horizontal ">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row" id="rptshow">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="card-box table-responsive">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
                                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PoId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PoId, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", disabled = "disabled" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", required = "required" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", required = "required", })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PostCode, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PostCode, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", required = "required", data_parsley_minlength = "4", type = "number", palceholder = "" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Hpo, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Hpo, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", required = "required", data_parsley_Maxlength = "2", data_parsley_minlength = "2", type = "number", palceholder = "" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Gpo, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Gpo, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", required = "required", data_parsley_Maxlength = "2", data_parsley_minlength = "2", type = "number", palceholder = "" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" id="add">Save changes</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Main View:

```
@{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        List<App.Domain.PostOffice> items = ViewBag.Items;
    }

    <link href="~/App_Themes/Theme1/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/App_Themes/Theme1/assets/css/pages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../App_Themes/Theme1/assets/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
        input[type="text"] {
            border: 1px solid #00ffff;
            background-color: white;
        }

        input[type="number"] {
            border: 1px solid #00ffff;
            background-color: white;
        }

        th {
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <div>
        <button id="addModalButton" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div id="modalDiv">

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <br /><h4 class="m-t-0 header-title"><b>Existing Post Office List </b></h4><br />
                <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead style="background:#4c5667;">
                        <tr>
                            <th>SL.</th>
                            <th>PO ID No</th>
                            <th>PO Name</th>
                            <th>PO Address</th>
                            <th>Post Code</th>
                            <th>HPO</th>
                            <th>GPO</th>
                            <th>Create By</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="postList">
                        @{
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            i = i + 1;
            <tr>
                <td>@i</td>
                <td>@item.PoId</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Address</td>
                <td>@item.PostCode</td>
                <td>@item.Hpo</td>
                <td>@item.Gpo</td>
                <td>@item.EntryUser</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="on-default edit-row editSup" data-id="@item.Id" id="edit" value="@item.Id"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
                        }

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreatePostOffice()
        {
            ViewBag.Items = _postOfficeService.All().ToList();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult CreatePosto(PostOffice aPostOffice)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var lastPo = _postOfficeService.All().ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.PoId == aPostOffice.PoId.Trim());
                if(lastPo!=null)
                {
                    aPostOffice.PoId = (Convert.ToInt32(lastPo.PoId) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(4,'0');
                }

                aPostOffice.EntryUser = User.Identity.Name;
                aPostOffice.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
                _postOfficeService.Add(aPostOffice);
                _postOfficeService.Save();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("CreatePostOffice");
        }
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer.

I pass the data from my controller to the Index view like this:

return View(await _context.Machines.Include(t => t.MachineTypes).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());

So, I suposse I should use the RenderPartial like this:

@Html.RenderPartial("Create", Models.Machines)

But I get: 'Models' doesn't exists in the actual context.

Comment: What actually do you want to pass list of machines.... if so you already declared in @model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Machine> .... so you just need to write.... only  @Html.RenderPartial("Create", Model) ... Not  @Html.RenderPartial("Create", Models.Machines)

Comment: Got this message

        Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'
+
                @Html.RenderPartial("Create", Model)      :(

Comment: Also tried this: 
                  @{Html.RenderPartial("Create", Model);} and got same initial error: "InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Application.Models.Machine]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Application.Models.Machine'."

Comment: I got it... if you know which model need to pass .. then write @Html.RenderPartial("Create", Model[0]) suppose I want to pass 0 index model

Comment: I edited the original question. I believe I wasn't giving the full context. Maybe now it can be understood better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Progress:**

Ok, so since I can't render a single model into the Index view to be used by the PartialView("Create") I did this:

```
            @foreach (var defectsVM in Model)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("Create", defectsVM);

            }
```

And well, no errors but when I click on the "create" link, it pop ups the Create form (yey) but of course, it doest it multiple times and bringing the data for each register in the Machine table.

How could I bring only one and that is a clean one?